# Need help showing $\left(\frac{n^2 - 2n + 1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n \to e^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to work out this limit:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2 - 2n + 1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n = e^2
$$
 I have managed to show that it is equal to: $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left (1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n$$ but I have no idea how to continue from here, help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are on the right track. Now observe that $\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\to 0$ and continue with the manipulation indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\left(\frac{n^2 - 2n + 1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n =\left(\frac{n^2 - 4n + 2+2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n =\left(1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n = \left[\left(1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^{\frac{n^2-4n+2}{2n-1}}\right]^\frac{n(2n-1)}{n^2-4n+2}$$

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid, but Im really struggling at this part. Im trying to find a way to remove the top exponent so I'll have the form of e times 1 to some power. But it seems like I cant get rid of the n's in the top exponent

Comment: @xXappleXxPie The limit of $[*]\to e$ and the limit of the exponent tends to $2$, from here we can easily conclude.

Comment: Wait, if you have a series raised to a series than does that mean that the limit is the limit of the first series raised to the second series?

Comment: @xXappleXxPie Yes we can evaluate the limits separately if we don't have an indeterminate form. In our case we have $[a_n]^{b_n}$ with $a_n \to e$ and $b_n \to 2$ and thus we can conlude that  $[a_n]^{b_n}\to e^2$.

Comment: @xXappleXxPie While in the original limit we have $(c_n)^n$ with $c_n \to 1$ and $n\to \infty$ which is an indeterminate form $1^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$A=\left (1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n\implies \log(A)=n\log \left (1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)$$ Now, using equivalents since $n$ is large
$$\log \left (1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)\sim \frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\sim \frac 2n$$ making $\log(A)\sim 2 \implies A \sim e^2$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left (1+f(x)\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[(1+f(x))^{1/f(x)}\right]^{xf(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{xf(x)}$$ and in your case, $$nf(n)=\frac{2n^2-n}{n^2-4n+2}\implies \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Applying the equivalent infinitesimal substitution $$\ln(1+x) \sim x,(x \to 0)$$

we have

\begin{align*}\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2 - 2n + 1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)^n &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \exp\left[n \cdot \ln \left(1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)\right]\\&=\exp\left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n \cdot \ln \left(1+\frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)\right)\right]\\
&=\exp\left[\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(n \cdot \frac{2n-1}{n^2-4n+2}\right)\right]\\&=e^2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a different approach, note that the desired limit is equivalent to proving

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2} \right)^n-\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^n \right)=0$$

The algebraic identity $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$) tells us (for $n\ge2$, so that all numerators and denominators are appropriately positive, and, toward the end, for $n\ge11$, for the sake of a simplifying bound)

$$\left|\left(1+{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2} \right)^n-\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^n\right|\\
=\left|{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2}-{2\over n} \right|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2} \right)^{n-1-k}\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^k\\
=\left(7n-4\over n^2-4n+2 \right){1\over n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2} \right)^{n-1-k}\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^k\\
\le\left(7n-4\over n^2-4n+2 \right){1\over n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2} \right)^n\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^n\\
=\left(7n-4\over n^2-4n+2 \right)\left(1+{2n-1\over n^2-4n+2} \right)^n\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^n\\
\le\left(7n-4\over n^2-4n+2 \right)\left(1+{3\over n} \right)^n\left(1+{2\over n} \right)^n\quad\text{if }n\ge11\\
\le\left(1000000\over n \right)e^5\to0\quad\text{as }n\to\infty$$

Note, in the final step I used an exaggerated upper bound for the linear-over-quadratic expression and the inequality $\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n\le e^x$ for all $n$ to bound $\left(1+{3\over n}\right)^n$ and$\left(1+{2\over n}\right)^n$ with $e^3$ and $e^2$, respectively. This isn't strictly necessary; we could have simply let $n\to\infty$ and gotten $0\cdot e^3\cdot e^2=0$, but it's nice, I thought, to have an expression that cleanly goes to zero.